# How to make an anchor with a div inside with a different link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to make a card that is all clickable (the class=box) Except for one section that contains buttons which each links to different links that its parent anchor..

I don't find a way to have one link for the card and a different for a section inside.

```
            <a class="box" href="box-link.html">
             <div class="box-text">
                <span>Some Text here</span>
                <div style="float:right; " ng-click="dosomeotherstuff()">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </div>
                <div style="float:right; " ng-click="somethignelse()">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
                </div>
             </div>
            </a>
```

I'm using Angular, hence the ng-clicks.

Any ideas on how to sort this out?

Adding a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/pepepapa82/svwLh6w1/

Comment: You can't validly nest an interactive element (`<a>`, `<button>`, `<input />` etc) within another interactive element.

Comment: that's what i thought. but, there must be a workaround right? making a clickable card with other links inside is imposible?

Answer (score 1):

You can add more than one action to an `ng-click`. In this case, you might want to first prevent the `click` event propogating, then trigger your sub-action:

```
        <a class="box" href="box-link.html">
         <div class="box-text">
            <span>Some Text here</span>
            <div style="float:right; " ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); dosomeotherstuff()">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; " ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); somethignelse()">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
        </a>
```

As an alternative, you could pass `$event` as the first argument of your functions, and stop propogation there. **This is, IMHO, cleaner**.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the response.. I'm not getting your suggestion to work. please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/pepepapa82/svwLh6w1/

Comment: add this **$event.preventDefault();** inside ng-click... _ng-click=" **$event.preventDefault();** $event.stopPropagation(); dosomeotherstuff()"_